Error messages when trying to connect to Oracle database using SQLcl
I downloaded SQLcl, unzipped it, sat the PATH system variable to point to its \bin, switched to command prompt (Windows 10), but then never managed to connect to my database (11g) with it. sql /nolog was as far as I could.
First, it said:
“Error Message = no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path: …”,
I searched and surprisingly found out it needs Oracle's "instant client" (Oracle says something along "just unzip and connect"). I download and install IC, run, and then another error message:
“Error Message = Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:211200230906, Jdbc-OCI:2115000”
I tried another ver. of IC (ver. 19), but received “cannot find ..” or something, so I switched back to the "incompatible version" (21_15). I'm using SQLcl release 24.2.0.180.1721.
Can you please help me with this??

The sol. is in Petr Barandovski's comment below.

You have probably in enviroments variables ORACLE_HOME for old version of Oracle. Sqlcl does not need oracle client, but it tries to use it probably. Try to run from cmd and first set SET ORACLE_HOME="" and then run sql.exe.

I don't have "ORACLE_HOME". I removed all references to IC from PATH, and now the error has become: "Error Message = no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path: ..."

What does your connect command look like? Or how are you starting sqlcl ?


SQL, then I supply the username: USER@127.0.0.1:1521/ORAAIPDB, then the password. And that's where I get the error.


try jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/password@127.0.0.1:1521/ORAAIPDB ?

Yes! It worked!! Thanks a billion. But what was the problem? Do I need to always supply that string for login?

I think, that problem is somewhere else, probably with some old installation of Oracle client. May be in registry? It Is only workaround

Press Windows + R, type sysdm.cpl.
Go to the Advanced tab, then click Environment Variables.
Under System Variables, find and select Path, then click Edit.
Add the full path to the Instant Client folder, for example: C:\oracle\instantclient_21_9\bin.

I did that when I installed IC.
